# How to join two table and update the table?

Tags: phpmyadmin

table1:

```
id,studname,course

1,AAA,EnglishI
1,AAA,Basic programming 
1,AAA,EnglishII
1,AAA,Maths
2,BBB,programming
2,BBB,IT Essential
2,BBB,Maths
```

table2:

```
1,AAA,(EnglishI,Basic programming,EnglishII,Maths)-serialization
2,BBB,(programming, IT Essential, Maths)
```

how?  kindly help me..

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Won't that break normalization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, studname, GROUP_CONCAT(course) FROM table GROUP BY studname
```